# what is the meaning in here? james lovelock, or living earth

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the meaning in here? james lovelock, or living earth
[image]

Comment: i didn't understand why they used living earth here

Comment: Did you read the article? According to Wikipedia, James Lovelock formulated the Gaia hypothesis, which proposes that 'living and non-living parts of the Earth form a complex interacting system that can be thought of as a single organism'. In other words, the whole Earth is like a living thing.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What do you think it should be? Why?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  They can't be searched or indexed, they're unfriendly to users with vision problems or using assistive technologies, *and they just generally don't help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use 'or' to separate the main title of a work such as an article, novel, story, film, play, etc, from a secondary or 'alternate' title. Often the main title will be someone's name, and the alternative title will give a hint or explanation of the work's subject. Titles like this may be thought old-fashioned and literary.

Here the main title is 'James Lovelock', and the alternate title is 'Living Earth'. The latter could refer to his theory that the Earth is like a living thing, and (I personally think) an additional nuance could be that Lovelock himself has been 'living' (loyally devoting his life to) the Earth (the article seems to be biographical).

As an example, Mary Shelley gave her most famous novel the title

> Frankenstein; or, The Modern Prometheus

Here *Frankenstein* is the main title, and *or, The Modern Prometheus* is the alternative title, by which she references the Greek Titan as a hint of the novel's themes. The punctuation is old-fashioned (the book was published in 1818).

Some more recent books and films have been titled this way:

> Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb (1964 film)

More modern practice seems to be to use a colon instead of 'or'.

> Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest

Possibly confusingly, publishers used to call an alternative title a 'subtitle' (it was printed in smaller type under the main title), but nowadays most people outside the publishing world use that word for on-screen text in films and TV programmes.

[Subtitle (titling) (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(titling)#:%7E:text=Another%20kind%20of%20subtitle%2C%20often,or%22%2C%20hence%20its%20appellation.)